# On Makefile, how to list folders where source files reside?

Tags: makefile

For my specific case, I have many folders and subfolders with .v files. I want to compile them folder by folder. I have made this:

```
# find folders and subfolders to work on
DIRS := $(wildcard */)
DIRS += $(shell find $(DIRS) -type d)

# compiler flags
SRC += *.v
COMPILE = $(general_compiler_flags) $(SRC)

# run the compiler
run:
    $(foreach d, $(DIRS), $(shell cd $d && $(COMPILE)))
```

But this takes all folders that do not have .v files and compiles them anyway. How do I make it so on my DIRS I have only the folders that house .v files?

Comment: If this is on a linux-like system then you could try something like `DIRS += $(shell find $(DIRS) -type f -name '*.v' -printf '%h\n' | sort -u)` .

Comment: This does exactly what I asked thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you use make functions (especially `shell`) in your recipes is not the recommended way to use make. Assuming you have simple directory names (no spaces, no special characters), you could use something like the following, instead:

```
VDIRS := $(sort $(foreach d,$(DIRS),$(if $(wildcard $(d)/*.v),$(d),)))

run:
    for d in $(VDIRS); do ( cd $$d && $(COMPILE); ); done
```

An even more make-ish solution would rely on make to iterate over all source directories instead of doing so inside a recipe:

```
VDIRS := $(sort $(foreach d,$(DIRS),$(if $(wildcard $(d)/*.v),$(d),)))

RUN-VDIRS := $(addprefix run-,$(VDIRS))
.PHONY: run $(RUN-VDIRS)

run: $(RUN-VDIRS)

$(RUN-VDIRS): run-%:
    cd $* && $(COMPILE)
```

And, finally, we should consider how to avoid useless re-compilations, but this is another, more complex, story.

Comment: This just prints the following in the terminal:
```for d in ; do ( cd $d && compiler_flags; ); done
```

Comment: Did you use just this or did you add it to your existing solution? Here, the first solution prints: `for d in a/ c/; do ( cd $d && echo "VCOM " *.v; ); done`, `VCOM  a.v` and `VCOM  c.v` (I defined `general_compiler_flags` as `echo "VCOM "`).

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't see $(DIRS) inside VDIRS (I had overwritten DIRS with your line). It obviously works now. Thank you so much for your answer as it gave me great insight on make!